# Parse migration from Javascript SDKs before 1.5.0

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have a pretty old app that uses js sdk version `1.2.1`. I have completed all other steps related to parse open source server and everything seems to fine. But, the thing I missed was to update JS sdk which is specified in step 7 of parse migration.

[7.Point Client to Local Parse Server](https://parse.com/migration)

Is there any possibility to keep the current backbone structure and use with parse-open-source server. My app uses almost all features of Parse, like parse push, parse files etc.

I have googled a lot, and tried [parsebone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parsebone). But, not found any guides to migrating apps from 1.5.0 to the new js sdk structure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: options possible ... https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [parsebone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parsebone) with few modification to use with `require.js` module and working without any other code change. :) I have commented the wrapper starting with:

```
var moduleExport

if ((typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) || (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports)) {
  moduleExport = {}
} else {
  moduleExport = this
}

;(function () {
```

and it works as expected.